# Jenkins unsupported build action 'archive'

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, ipa

I'm using Jenkins to build .ipa 
but there are errors when codesigning.
why archive command unsupported?

The error I'm getting is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ginav-mobile/build/Distribution-iphoneos/ginav-mobile.app

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

=== BUILD TARGET ginav-mobile OF PROJECT ginav-mobile WITH CONFIGURATION Distribution ===

Check dependencies
unsupported build action 'archive'
Code sign error: No command to generate product wrapper at '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ginav-mobile/build/Distribution-iphoneos/ginav-mobile.app'.

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

Comment: Why don't you mark your question as correctly answered by Tamara?

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error. I managed to solve it after reading this [thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/322803-xcodebuild-archive-fails-if-given-target-ok-if-scheme.html).
The Xcode plugin seems to be using "-target" on the archive command, which not sure why doesn't work (anymore?)

What worked for me was: Instead of letting the plugin do the archive, I added an additional build step `"Execute shell"` with this command:

```
 "xcodebuild -project "TestApp.xcodeproj" -scheme "TestApp" -configuration Debug archive"
```

More in depth

In Jenkins:

In your project configuration under "Build" in step "Xcode" under "General build settings" uncheck "Generate Archive?"

[image: uncheck-generate-archive]

On "Add build step" drop-down select "Execute Shell"
Write this command with your respective App name and the Configuration (Debug) you need.

```
xcodebuild -project "TestApp.xcodeproj" -scheme "TestApp" -configuration Debug archive
```

[image: archive-command]

Now in Xcode, make sure your the Scheme is set to Shared and the Scheme Data is commited and pushed as well. 
Done in "Manage Scheme"

[image]

Otherwise Jenkins won't find your Scheme and will show an error similar to:

```
The project 'TestApp' does not contain a scheme named 'TestApp2'
```

This should make your app archive, hopefully it helps!
This should create your archive.

PS: To make the Jenkins with Xcode setup I used this nice [guide](http://www.chrisboyd.net/post/25806571422/github-jenkins-testflight-part-2-building-your)